# Are there DNS performance differences, between macs vs fedora on home networks FIOS?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, isp

I recently switched my home network provider to verizon's fios, which proves to be very fast for external internet access.

Oddly, however:

- On one of my laptops which is connected to an ethernet port, DNS pinging can be VERY slow at times (and sometimes, hosts like www.google.com are not 
  even resolved at all).
- This same laptop has modern hardware, has always performed well on several other networks, and has fedora 22 installed on it.
- This laptop interconnects to other laptops very fast.  Thus I assume the ethernet port isn't to blame.  Local connections happen in < 20 ms.
- the other machines (all MacBooks) on the network can easily resolve any external website in 20 ms or lest, thus I know the overall FIOS network is reasonably fast.

It thus seems that DNS works differently on Fedora 22 than on my Mac laptops, and in particular, works poorly on Verizon's FIOS.  Is that possible ?

I thus have several questions, the main one being:

**Are there special steps I should take when using a linux machine  on  a home network using a verizon Router on a FIOS network?**

Related questions:

- Are there any reasons why a non-standard (i.e. ubuntu, fedora, ...) computer might have **poor DNS** on Verizon's FIOS ?
- How can I improve the performance of **external host resolution** on this particular fedora machine ?
- Is DNS performance somehow different depending on the type of operating system you are using ?

Comment: UPDATE: I checked on my mac - and the DNS server is the same one as my linux /etc/resolv.conf... Meaning there must be some other reason that DNS is so slow on the linux box.  Maybe the mac laptop caches DNS entries better?

Comment: How slow is it? And does `nslookup` report the correct nameserver?

Comment: Each OS has a (semi-configurable) name source lookup order, based on the protocols allowed. Since most systems read the host file first, a lookup on a system with a very large host file would take longer. if the system is configured to perform WINS or NETBIOS name lookups before attempting DNS lookup, it would waste some time. Additionally a large number of search domains might make a "shortname" resolution take longer, and finally, most linuxes don't do DNS caching, unless specially configured to do so, but Windows (and Mac, I believe) do cache DNS responses for quick resolution.

Comment: you may want to try the GRC DNS benchmarking untility, to see if your results are actually that divergent, and hopefully get some hints as to why. https://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm

Comment: Another thing to check is whether the DNS query is being resolved over TCP or UDP. UDP is the traditional protocol, but because of issues with NAT-mappings for connection-less protocols TCP has become a common option. some OSes default to TCP first, but others use it as a fallback. it may be a good idea to sniff on a query, with a tool like Wireshark, and confirm that the OSes are attempting to resolve in the same manner.

Comment: Oddly, I've reinstalled Fedora 20 on this laptop, and the network is working now.  Possibly a fresh installation of NetworkManager was required.... of course i'll update this thread tomorrow if that changes :)